# How to access camera in Samsung smart tv emulator

Tags: camera, samsung-smart-tv

We building an app for Samsung Smart TV. We want to connect to camera to support gestures and video recording.
But we are unable to connect to camera.
We tried this tutorial http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00037/index.html#how-to-use-at-sdk-emulator

The log says -

```
[JS ALERT]: Create SEF Plugin for Camera: <object id="..">
[JS ALERT]: SEF Open Returns 0
[JS ALERT]: SEF Open Failed!!!
[JS ALERT]: CANNOT get plugin object (Camera)
[JS ALERT]: [deviceapis.js] camera not supported
[JS ALERT]: state false
```

How can we connect to camera?
Is there any better source other than samsungdforum.com?

Comment: Where you tested your application, in Emulator or Samsung Smart TV device?

Comment: I tested by application first on emulator, and we couldn't connect the    camera/webcam to emulator. Finally we deployed the app on smart tv where we could easily access the TV camera.

Comment: Yes, it is because emulator not support camera, voice and gesture functionality